# Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, printing

[ng] ./node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js:1:0-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in 'D:\Angular\Ionic\printer4\node_modules\zlib\lib'
[ng]

**any solution**

I am tring to print the data from ionic app using node-thermal-printer ionic/angular

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you installed a library that is not compatible with the imports that Angular is ok with (due to Webpack)
Maybe you could take a look at this version :
https://github.com/MadfishDT/zlibt

Also, you could try to give a little bit more code in your questions, this way it's easier to figure it out.
Cheers.